# Android/iOS trigger action after connecting to USB

Tags: android, ios

I'm going to create a mobile phone charger, that is accessible in public (like in bars or restaurants). Now I'm looking for a method to show to my "clients" an information about the device (about the sponsor).

Is it possible to trigger opening a webpage, after connecting the mobile phone to a USB port? Or ask the user to install an app? The port can be in a PC (not a charge-only port). I've read about "universal accessories", which can do a lot, but it looks quite complicated to create a charging "accessory" only to display a web-page.

Has anyone an better idea? Any other actions (other than opening a web page / asking to install an app) are possible?

Answer (score 0):

Open it on a PC? Probably. On Android not without installing an app to do that or using Tasker.

Read up on Intents and specifically how to listen for `Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` if you want to have people install an app in order to use the charger.